# How to use smart pointer for auto clean-up?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, stream, smart-pointers

I'm making a simple logging class with a pointer to either a `std::ofstream` or `std::cerr`.

Is there any simple way to use a smart pointer for auto clean-up regardless of which stream is used?

The code must compile on clang++, g++, and VS2013.

### Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

class Logger {
private:
    std::ostream * output_stream{ nullptr };
    bool using_file{ false };
public:
    Logger()
    {
        output_stream = &std::cerr;
        using_file = false;
    }
    Logger(std::string file)
    {
        output_stream = new std::ofstream(file);
        using_file = true;
    }
    ~Logger()
    {
        if (using_file)
        {
            delete output_stream;
        }
    }
    template<typename T>
    void log(T info)
    {
        *output_stream << info << std::endl;
    }
};

class tmp {
    int i{ 4 };
    friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &os, const tmp& p);
};

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const tmp& p)
{
    return os << p.i;
}

int main()
{
    tmp t;
    Logger logger;
    logger.log(t);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

### Attempts

#### `std::unique_ptr`

I can use `std::unique_ptr` for the file like so:

```
std::unique_ptr<std::ostream> p;
p = std::make_unique<std::ofstream>("file.txt");
*p << "hi there" << std::endl;
```

Trying this with `std::cout` warns me about a deleted function (assuming that's the constructor.

```
std::unique_ptr<std::ostream> p2;
p2 = std::make_unique<std::ostream>(std::cout);
*p2 << "hey" << std::endl;
```

#### `std::shared_ptr`

Because `std::unique_ptr` is only for owning things, and `std::cout` shouldn't be owned, I thought I'd try `std::shared_ptr`

```
std::shared_ptr<std::ostream> p;
p = std::make_shared<std::ostream>(std::cout);
*p << "hola" << std::endl;
```

It gives me the same deleted constructor error. `p = &std::cout` complains about a type mismatch, so it's also not working.

Comment: `shared_ptr` is only for owning things, too. Also assigning `cout` to a smart pointer doesn't make sense, you can't delete it anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `shared_ptr` with a deleter that does not delete anything in the case of `cerr` and just a normally constructed `shared_ptr` in the case of `ofstream`

```
class Logger {
private:
    std::shared_ptr<std::ostream> output_stream{ nullptr };

public:
    Logger() :
        output_stream(&std::cerr, [](std::ostream*){})
    { }

    Logger(std::string file) :
        output_stream(std::make_shared<std::ofstream>(file))
    { }

    // default destructor is OK

    template<typename T>
    void log(T info)
    {
        *output_stream << info << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Comment: I'm choosing this answer because it looks the simplest. It's shorter than my code and doesn't need a raw pointer of any type. Thanks!

Comment: A `shared_ptr` seems a bit overkill to me.

Comment: @ChrisDrew This doesn't work with `unique_ptr` because of the variable custom deleter.

Comment: @zenith Clearly. I'm not claiming you can drop in `unique_ptr` into this answer. If you want to use `unique_ptr` you need something more like our answers. I was suggesting it was unnecessary to pay for the overhead of a `shared_ptr` if you don't need shared ownership.

Comment: @ChrisDrew Oh okay. True, I agree. Although this code looks very clever (which of course is not necessarily always a good thing).

Comment: @zenith Clever yes,  although perhaps potentially missleading.  If I see a `shared_ptr` I expect it to have some ownership of the thing it is pointing at.  On the plus side this does have reasonable copy behaviour for free if you want that.

Answer (score 5):

I would just have two pointers, one smart and one raw.

The raw pointer is always used to refer to the stream. The smart pointer is just used for clean-up if needed.

```
class Logger {
private:
    std::unique_ptr<std::ofstream> file_stream;
    std:ostream *stream;
public:
    Logger() : stream(&std::cerr) {}
    Logger(const std::string& file)
    : file_stream(std::make_unique<std::ofstream>(file)), stream(file_stream.get()){}

    template<typename T>
    void log(T info) {
        *stream << info << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I tend to try to avoid cases where I want an object to "own" such things. In the times I did not have much choice, I ended up settling with a "shouldDelete" flag or a callback.

```
class Logger {
public:
    Logger(std::ofstream *outputStream, bool deleteOutputStream)
        : outputStream(outputStream), deleteOutputStream(deleteOutputStream)
    {  }
    ~Logger()
    {
        if (deleteOutputStream) delete outputStream;
    }
};
Logger logger(&std::cout, false);

class Logger {
public:
    typedef std::function<void(std::ostream*)> Deleter;
    typedef std::unique_ptr<std::ostream, Deleter> OStreamPointer;
    Logger(OStreamPointer &&outputStream)
        : outputStream(std::move(outputStream))
    {  }
    ~Logger() { }
private:
    OStreamPointer outputStream;
};

Logger logger(Logger::OStreamPointer(
    &std::cout,
    [](std::ostream*) {})); //no-op callback
```

Comment: Do either of these options give me some advantage over my code? The first looks like mine, and the second still requires me to supply a delete function (every time I construct a Logger, no less). Do I get some form of generality that I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by releasing the smart pointer in the destructor (and elsewhere) in the cases where it shouldn't be deleted, but that's not worth the hassle IMO.

Instead, I'd recommend simply using two pointers: one for streams that need to be managed and one for those that don't:

```
class Logger {
private:
    std::ostream * unmanaged_stream{ nullptr };
    std::unique_ptr<std::ostream> managed_stream{ nullptr };
    bool using_file{ false };
    std::ostream& output_stream()
    {
        return using_file ? *managed_stream : *unmanaged_stream;
    }
public:
    Logger()
    : unmanaged_stream{&std::cerr},
      using_file{false}
    {
    }
    Logger(const std::string& file)
    : managed_stream{std::make_unique<std::ofstream>(file)},
      using_file{true}
    {
    }
    template<typename T>
    void log(T info)
    {
        output_stream() << info << std::endl;
    }
};
```

If saving space is a priority you could put them in a union, but then you'd have to explicitly call the destructor and placement new to define the active member, which again is more hassle and probably not worth it.

Comment: I chose ex-bart's answer because it's the shortest, but I really liked this one as well. Thanks!

Comment: @Ben Wow ex-bart's solution is clever, thanks for the reminder!